# Solving a system of PDE in many variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I want to solve a system of partial differential equations of the form

$\sum_{kl} A_{ikl}\frac{\partial u_{kj}}{\partial x_l}+\sum_k B_{ik} x_k u_{kj}=c_{ij}$

where $u_{ij}(x_1,...,x_N)$ are the unknown functions to be determined, $A_{ikl}$, $B_{ik}$ and $c_{ij}$ are known and do not depend on $u_{ij}$ or $x_k$. Is there a method to solve this kind of equations, e.g. a generalization of the characteristic method? Could you suggest me some references?

Comment: If it wasn't for the 2nd term, it would be a tensor equation, but tensors do not sum products of three independent factors over indices like that.